# Can I read the stream from TcpClient in a better way?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a system where in one end I have a device communicating with a module via RS-232.
The module is connected to a PC via TCP, and translates TCP messages to RS-232 and vice versa.

This is how I do it:

1. I read out every byte on the stream
2. build a string
3. compare the latter part of the string to a delimiter
4. then I stop reading the stream (and fire an event, though not shown here).

My current code for handling this is

```
        string delimiter = "\r\n";
        byte[] reply = new byte[1];
        string replyString = string.Empty;
        bool readOk = true;
        int dl = delimiter.Length;
        bool delimiterReached = false;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                stream.Read(reply, 0, 1);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                readOk = false;
                break;
            }

            replyString += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(reply, 0, reply.Length);

            int rl = replyString.Length;

            if (rl > dl)
            {
                string endString = replyString.Substring(rl-dl, dl);
                if (endString.Equals(delimiter))
                    delimiterReached = true;
            }

        } while (!delimiterReached);
```

where `stream` is the `TcpClient.GetStream()`

I don't much care for the constant string building, so I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: You're right not to like the constant string building. This code will make a new string every time a byte arrives. Take a look at `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Wouldn't I still lose some performance in the `string endString = stringBuilder.ToString(rl-dl, dl);`?

Comment: Just do the check straight on the stringbuilder object: "delimiterReached = (StringBuilder.ToString().Substring(start, length) == delimiter);" <-- sets the boolean to either true or false.

Answer (score 4):

Once the TCP connection is established, wrap the `TcpClient` stream in a `StreamReader`:

```
var reader = new StreamReader( stream, Encoding.ASCII );
```

Since your delimiter is `\r\n`, `StreamReader.ReadLine` will read a complete message:

```
var reply = reader.ReadLine();
```

Be careful to create the `StreamReader` once per TCP connection; it may read and buffer additional data from the underlying TCP stream for efficiency.

Comment: I can see from the implementation that it's mainly based on char[] buffers, and little string(building), so I guess it is faster. However, my delimiter is not always \r\n, sometimes it's "END OF FILE", or some other crazy stuff.